# Return the Value of an SQL NVARCHAR to a C# String

Tags: c#, sql, variables

All, this is something I have not had to do before and I cannot locate a simalar question for some reason. I wish to return the `NVARCHAR @columnHeaders` to a `String` in C#. The SQL query that will build the string I want is this

```
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @columnHeaders = 
    COALESCE (@columnHeaders + ',[' + Field + ']', '[' + Field + ']') 
FROM SomeTable;
```

However, how do I then pull the variable `@columnHeaders` back into C#? Note, I could use a function etc., but I do not want to use Stored Procedures, Views or Functions unless absolutely neccessary...

I can select the the columnn headers in to a `DataTable` using

```
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT COALESCE (@columnHeaders + ',[' + Field + ']', '[' + Field + ']') 
FROM SomeTable;
```

and manipulate in C#, but it would be nice to return the string direct from SQL.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `I do not want to use Stored Procedures, Views or Functions unless absolutely necessary ` Can you explain your reasoning here?

Comment: @asawyer: There are lots of reasons to avoid SPs unless absolutely necessary (complexity, debugging, error handling, separation of code, ...). [Here's a nice rant about them](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html)

Comment: @Heinzi most of which are utterly spurious. Putting SQL into C# is akin to using SendKeys to manipulate Windows.

Comment: @Heinzi Those are the exact reason's I'd give to encourage use of Sprocs/funcs ect.

Comment: @asawyer: I understand (I've given this topic a lot of thought in the past), but still disagree. Anyway, I don't think it makes sense to discuss this in detail here, just wanted to point out that a case can be made against them and "using SPs is always a win" is not automatically true.

Comment: @Heinzi I think it is relevant. OP is asking "I have a nail I'd like to hammer, but I don't want to use a hammer." I'd like to know what's wrong with using a hammer?

Comment: +1 for writing statements with semicolon

Comment: The reason for not wanting to use sps etc., is as @Heinzi correctly pointed out. I do not want to add sps, functions and views to a reporting database that I will eventually give to my users. I could create and sp then drop it, but this seems over-kill. SQL Server is used for many different kinds of application - and different approcahes are used for different things...

Comment: @MichaelBuen someone obviously did not like this question!? Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use stored procedures, this will probably work.

```
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX);  
    SELECT @columnHeaders =  
    COALESCE (@columnHeaders + ',[' + Field + ']', '[' + Field + ']')  
    FROM SomeTable; 
    select @columnHeaders
```

and use `ExecuteScalar()` to get the results.

However, I would personally recommend a stored procedure as being far neater, in that it keeps the SQL in the SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the second statement is non-set-returning, it will become an assignment process:

```
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @columnHeaders = 
    COALESCE (@columnHeaders + ',[' + Field + ']', '[' + Field + ']') 
FROM SomeTable;
```

You have to do this, just add the selection of @columnHeaders at the last line:

```
DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @columnHeaders = 
    COALESCE (@columnHeaders + ',[' + Field + ']', '[' + Field + ']') 
FROM SomeTable;
select @columnHeaders as ch;
```

Then on your C#:

```
da.Fill(dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0]["ch"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to store the data in a viriable if you just want the query to return it.

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(COALESCE (@columnHeaders + ',[' + Field + ']', '[' + Field + ']')  AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM SomeTable;
```

Comment: I think he wants to concatenate a bunch of records into a single string.

Comment: @podiluska True. And in SQL Server you cannot implicitly declare a variable, unlike in MySQL